# Table join and group by id mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the scenario:

1. I want to get customer names from Table 1
2. Join table 2 by id
3. Selecting all payment dates from table 2
4. Grouping by year

Just to explain, the code and name key belong to Table1 paymentDate and amount keys are on Table2 but they share foreign key the uniqueId key.

The expected result should end up like this:

```
[{
"code": 1011,
"name": "Customer1",
"amount": 5000,
"paymentDate": "2016-10-20T04:00:00.000Z"
"paymentDate": "2016-11-20T04:00:00.000Z"
"paymentDate": "2016-12-20T04:00:00.000Z"
},
{
"code": 1012,
"name": "Customer2",
"amount": 5000,
"paymentDate": "2016-03-20T05:00:00.000Z"
"paymentDate": "2016-04-20T05:00:00.000Z"
"paymentDate": "2016-05-20T05:00:00.000Z"
"paymentDate": "2016-06-20T05:00:00.000Z"
},
{
"code": 1013,
"name": "Customer3",
"amount": 5000,
"paymentDate": "2016-01-20T05:00:00.000Z"
"paymentDate": "2016-02-20T05:00:00.000Z"
 }]
```

So far i have this:

```
SELECT coreObjects.code,
       coreObjects.name,
       lateobjectpayments.amount,
       lateobjectpayments.paymentDate 
FROM   coreObjects 
JOIN   lateobjectpayments 
       ON coreObjects.uniqueId=lateobjectpayments.uniqueId
GROUP BY YEAR(lateobjectpayments.paymentDate)
```

It seems I need a multi select near the join but not having what I want so far. I will appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: I'm not seeing in your example where you are doing the grouping by year. Is that the problem you are stuck on?

Comment: actually the grouping by year is missing on the query but still that doesn;t give me what i want

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: The output with the query above is each customer is multiplied by paymentDate, so let say there are  4 payment dates for a single customer and i have an output of 4 results each have a payment date and other details above. The idea is to get all payments that a customer has made within a year and basically i need the name of customer and the code taken from Table 1 then attach to this customer all payment dates from table 2 which then needs to be grouped by year because a customer may have payed 4 times in 2016 and 2 times in 2017

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't mix group by aggregation (which consolidates several original tuples into one result tuple) and details selection (which requires all the original tuples) within a single group by statement.
If you write a query with a clause `GROUP BY YEAR(lateobjectpayments.paymentDate)`, then the result will comprise at most one tuple for every year, and there will be only one customer and paymentDate associated with such a result tuple.

Hence, split the query into subqueries; one for getting the aggregated values (i.e. `amount`) per `uniqueId` and `year`, and others for "getting back" the details:

```
select c.*, aggr.amount, lop.*
from (select uniqueId, year(paymentDate) as year, sum(amount) as amount from
lateobjectpayments
group by uniqueId, year(paymentDate)) aggr
join coreObjects c on c.uniqueId = aggr.uniqueId
join lateobjectpayments lop on year(lop.paymentDate)=aggr.year and lop.uniqueId = aggr.uniqueId
```

Note that sql results are of tabular form and not semistructured as, for example, json. But deriving a semistructured form from a tabular form in any programming language of your choice should be easy.